# what does the '.' in state name in Angularjs state provider mean?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

what is the significance of '.' in  state('xxx.yyy') in Angularjs 1.x?

Q1) Are the 2 states **emAllTickets.closed** and **emAllTickets/closed** are different? what is the significance of . and / here?

Q2) if i have a html code which routes to /closed, will it call both? emAllTickets and emAllTickets.closed?

sample code:

```
.state('emAllTickets',
      angularAMD.route({
            url: '/emAllTickets?locaID&type&gId',
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/emAllTickets/emAllTickets.html',
        controllerUrl: 'app/controllers/emAllTickets/emTicketsTableCtrl.js',
        resolve:{
              checkTrinityAccess: function($q,commonService){
                  var deferred = $q.defer();
                  commonService.verifyTrinityRestriction(deferred);
                  return deferred.promise;
              }
           }
      })
  )

.state('emAllTickets.closed',
      angularAMD.route({
            url: '/closed',
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/emAllTickets/closed.html'
      })
  )


.state('emAllTickets/closed',
      angularAMD.route({
            url: '/emAllTickets/closed',
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/emAllTickets/emAllTickets.html',
        controllerUrl: 'app/controllers/emAllTickets/emTicketsTableCtrl.js'
      })
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1) Yes, they are different. According to the [docs](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) the '.' notation creates a parent/child state.

Q2) Yes, the whole parent to child path gets active.

Comment: So, if i have a html code which routes to  /closed, will it call both?    emAllTickets and emAllTickets.closed?

Comment: I highly recommend taking some time to read the ui-router [wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki). It's just 5 chapters and it pays off! The router is such a **core** feature in (nearly) every AngularJS (1) SPA and there is much to know and to say about ui-router. **Not** knowing certain router features leads to very awkward implementations and a lot of pain. So, my advice is: definitely take your time and understand the router, do not guess, it's important.